# Error al copiar una matriz en otra en c

Tags: c, matrices

La verdad me pasa algo muy raro es que copio una matriz en otra como lo e hecho siempre pero se copia mal dejo [foto](https://ibb.co/BKPLJmW).

[image: Error al copiar una matriz en otra en c]

Como ven en la foto se copia bien las primeras 3 columnas pero la 4 copia la primera con un espacio corrido hacia abajo y después copia lo que esta en la 4 columna en la ultima sin razón(debe existir una razón pero no se cual es ), si alguien sabe porque pasa estaría agradecido voy a dejar el código.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

        char *p=getenv("USER");
        char frase[1024];

        printf("  [>>] Entroduce un frase para cifrar.\n" );
        printf("    %s~$ ",p );
        scanf("%s", frase);

        int clavei[3][3];
        int subclave[3][43];
        int rotword[3][0];

        int x,y;
        int nram;
        int i,j;
        int aux; 

        for(i=0 ; i<=3 ; i++){
                for(j=0 ; j<=3 ; j++){
                        nram =  0 + rand() % ((255 + 0) - 0);
                        clavei[i][j] = nram;
                        printf("%x ,", clavei[i][j]);
                }

                printf("\n");
        }

        printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n");                                                   
        for(i=0 ; i<=3 ; i++){
                for(j=0 ; j<=43 ; j++){
                        subclave[i][j] = 0;
                }
        }

        for(i=0 ; i<=3 ; i++){
                for(j=0 ; j<=3 ; j++){
                        subclave[i][j] = clavei[i][j];
                }

        }


        for(i=0 ; i<=3 ; i++){
                for(j=0 ; j<=43 ; j++){
                        printf("%x ,", subclave[i][j]);
                }

                printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("  Adios :)\n");                                         
        return 0;                                                                       
}
```

Comment: No veo error en la logica, lo unico que estas definiendo por ejemplo:

`int clavei[3][3];`

y en los ciclos `for` estas recorriendo hasta 3 inclusive, tendría que darte error de que se va de limites.

Comment: @FrancoRolando No entiendo lo que quieres decir? como que se va de los limites? al ejecutar no me manda ni un error

Comment: Eso es lo raro, Pongo el siguiente ejemplo:

Comment: Eso es lo raro, Pongo un ejemplo: si tienes una matriz con 3 filas y 3 columnas como es tu caso, en un ciclo `for` cuando recorres desde 0 hasta igual que 3, lo que sucede es que la posicion el [0,0] es el primer elemento primer fila, [0,1] segundo elemento primer fila, [0,2] tercer elemento primer fila, Y COMO EL 3 esta incluido haces [0,3] cuarto elemento primer fila, pero tu declaraste la matriz como 3 filas 3 columnas osea 3 elementos por fila, ni mas ni menos.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion a tu problema es sacar en los ciclos for la condicion de menor o igual estrico, añado imagenes demostrando el funcionamiento erroneo al dejar el igual.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Vemos como la ultima columna toma valores erróneos,  mientras que las columnas internas toman los valores que deben tener. Pero si sacamos los menor igual pasa lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Toma los valores correctos, sin salto que voy obteniendo de mi acumulador. Espero que se entienda.

Comment: En la caso de mi codigo la matriz es de 4x4 ya que empieza con el indice 0 por ejemplo clavei[0][0] es : "a3" y la otra esquina que seria clavei[3][3] es: "e2" pero entiendo a lo que te refieres voy a cambiar los "=" para ver que pasa al llegar a mi casa y te comento si funciona

Comment: si es de 4x4, entonces declarala como `int x[4][4]` y ahi si puedes usar <= 3 o en su defecto <4.